# What breakpad height for 256mm disc

Tags: brake-rotor, opel, brake-pad, disk-brakes, vectra

I am going to replace the front break discs and brake pads of my opel vectra b 1997 1.6 16V sedan . The discs are ZIMMERMANN 430.1461.20 256mm. But I cant decide between ate brake pads 13.0460-7052.2 and 13.0460-7091.2. The main difference is that the first model is 52.3mm heigh and the second one is 74mm. Both models are said te be able to fit my car, but I'm not sure about the height. Are the bigger ones going to fit the 256mm disc, or should I go for the smaller ones? I don't want to waste the disc's break area, but I also don't want to buy the bigger pads and find out that they are too high.

Comment: I'm seeing both pad sizes listed as well, but I only see the single size of rotor listed. If it were a betting man, I'd suggest either size will fit ... but it's anyone's guess. Hopefully someone will have some experience with these and can tell you definitively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've found the answer. I've bought the smaller pads and yesterday i've put the new discs and pads and they fit perfectly. So the bigger (74mm) pads wouldn't fit the 256mm discs. Anyway thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Go with these 13.0460-7052.2, no complaints from people who use them in the UK. As far as the dealership goes even they recommend the smaller brake pads with the current calipers installed (OEM). Now yes, you can go bigger, but it hasn't been tested or reported on the vectra with OEM calipers. I would strongly suggest getting the smaller pads due to the engineering and stability at hand while these cars were engineered. Of course the dealership follows the same protocol.